# Disable stdout output in UART

Tags: stdout, uart

When PetaLinux is loaded, messages are sent to the screen and duplicated in the UART(dev/ttyPS0), which I need to use for data exchange. How to disable stdout output in UART?

Comment: Stdout is associated with a session or shell.  Are you actually referring to  the system console?

Comment: STDOUT is redirect to the serial console. This hinders the use of UART as a serial port. UART looked through different programs to work with the COM-port.

Comment: Is there a  shell-command to disable the stdout to the serial port (UART)?

Comment: Try (a) remove this serial terminal from any `console` specification in the kernel command line, (b) remove this serial terminal from any `getty` command in the **/etc/inittab** file.